# Fast Queries over subarrays

Tags: algorithm, c++11, optimization, range-query

**Problem**: Given an sorted array of integers a[N], I have to process queries of kind as follow

- [L R] p : find  sum of <sup>a<sub>i</sub></sup>C<sub>p</sub> for all i=L...R

**Constraints**: 
  N< 10<sup>5</sup> 
  1<=a<sub>i</sub><=10<sup>6</sup>

Suppose there are Q such queries , Then please suggest a better method to solve this problem. Some points to note are 
All queries are given in advance , i.e. offline algorithm can work . 
Also note that the array is sorted. 
each element in the array is bounded by small number.
There are no updates to the array.

Thanks

PS: brute force approach is processing each query element by element which would give complexity: O(Q * N * (cost of n choose r) )  .

Comment: What is your question? It currently seems like you want us to do your work, which stackoverflow isn't for.

Comment: No, I just want to know a fast way to process such a large number of queries. I don't want any code , I just want ideas and links.

Comment: a_i C p is Choose(a_i,p)?

Comment: Try splitting the problem: compute _c_i = Choose(a_i, p)_; support queries about _sum c_L … c_R_.

Comment: @greybeard but, p is not fixed for all the queries.

Comment: Any constraints for `p`?

Comment: @PhamTrung, p is ultimately bounded by ai, which is less than 1 million.

Comment: @cc2, this is an obfuscated version of [Chef and String](http://www.codechef.com/JUNE15/problems/CHSTR), isn't it?

Comment: If this is `Chef ans String`, the problem is much easier.

Comment: @PhamTrung, may be, but we should not help cc2 to solve the problem before [the contest](http://www.codechef.com/JUNE15/) is finished (three days left).

Comment: @dened, @PhamTrung: I don't see the problems to be closely related, thanks for keeping an eye out, anyway. Precomputing f_0 = 1, f_i = a_i!/a_i-1! seems an idea (even being sorted would help). Do the `p`s have to be no greater than a_L (, is the result well-defined otherwise)?

Comment: @greybeard let's wait for OP come back and confirm, the point is for `C`, we need to divide each term by `(ai - p)!`, so pre-calculated table may not work in this case, and, this problem may not have a solution. However, if this is `Chef and String`, it is easier, I solved that problem yesterday.

Comment: @greybeard, just notice that every _ai_ is the number of occurrences of the corresponding substring _si_ in _S_ (_S_ is from [Chef and String](http://www.codechef.com/JUNE15/problems/CHSTR)). And _p_ of _i_-th query is _Ki_ from Chef and String.

Comment: @dened: so, how does Choose(a_i, p) relate to sum over Choose(a_i, p) for L <= i <= R?

Comment: @greybeard , for a query `q`, so we need to return all ways to choose `q` from  q, q + 1, ... n equivalent substrings, so that make sense.

Comment: @greybeard, sum over Choose(ai, p) for 1 <= _i_ <= _N_ is the answer to Chef and String.

Comment: @cc2 can you clarify this? is this problem `Chef and String`? can you post a link to the original problem if possible?

Comment: link to Chef and String is posted above comments by @dened .